# How to remove sub key in mongodb using laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I'm using jenssegers mongodb package.

This is my collections

```
DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('users')->insertGetId(array('name' => 'John Doe', 'users' => [
            [
                'id' => 100,
                'wallet'=>20.20
            ],
            [
                'id' => 101,
                'wallet'=>10.66
            ]
        ]));
```

I'm trying to delete particular `wallet` record. following is the code

```
DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('users')->where('name', 'John Doe')->where('users.id',100)->unset('users.wallet');
```

But its not working as expected. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What does it mean, its not working as expected? What happens?

Comment: Its not removing the `wallet` key

Answer (score 2):

To unset a field from a subdocument array you have to write `users.$.wallet` instead of `users.wallet`

```
DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('users')->where('name', 'John Doe')->where('users.id',100)->unset('users.$.wallet');
```

Take a look at the [official unset documentation of mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/#behavior). In section behaviour the `$` - sign will be explained.